# Advertising: How does CPI (cost per install) tracking works?

Tags: android, ios, admob, ads

I'm seeing a couple advertising network using CPI instead of the traditional CPC/CPM. So what happens is the ads is clicked on the web / mobile browser, and then the user goes to download the app from the appstores. Some ad networks are able to track these installs and linked them to the clicks.

Browsers typically doesn't contain information on UDID, open format, MAC address or any identification, so how are the ad networks able to link them?

Note: For both Android & iOS.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically Google Campaign tracking as found on Google Play Store campaign tracking found on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns.

It's basically an url to the store download page like

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.app&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26utm_term%3Drunning%252Bshoes%26utm_content%3DdisplayAd1%26utm_campaign%3Dshoe%252Bcampaign

**Note:** Note that the referrer parameter is escaped and passed as ONE `referrer` parameter.

The referrer parameter is passed to the device when the App is being installed. You'll need to integrate certain library (can be AdMob, GoogleAnalytics or multiple) you need to integrate can listen to the INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast, read the information and send it back to the server (i.e. of the ad company).

Comment: Dunno about iOS, it would probably have similar. I've only worked with Google. But the campaign tracking `utm_*` fields are used for Google Analytics tracing and just taken over by other frameworks.